# The same function works when using GHCI, but not in VS code

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and I am trying to write a function that replaces the first and the last element of a an array. When writing my code in GHCI, it works fine, but in VS Code it gives an error saying "parse error". My guess is that "let" works not the way that I assumed. Here is the function:

```
swap1 :: [x] -> [x]
swap1 [] = error "empty list"
swap1 [x] = error "one element list"
swap1 let a = head x
swap1 let b = last x
swap1 let y = init x
swap1 let z = tail y
swap1 = b:z ++ [a]
```

Comment: This doesn't work in ghci, it gives *"parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"* on the first line using `let`.

Comment: By GHCI i meant if I run every line of code seperately

Comment: Yes, that's the error you'll get because `swap1 let a = head x` is just nonesense.

Comment: I wrote it without swap1, because I do not declare a function in GHCI. And if it's nonsense, then please explain what is wrong.

Comment: See that's why you don't modify code and make claims about the modified code that only apply to the unmodified one, see my answer for what's wrong. `let a = head x` (provided that `x` is defined) defines a new variable on ghci, which of course is *not* nonesense, `swap1 let a = head x` however is.

Comment: Sorry about that. I saw your answer, it works, thank you, but can I declare a variable without using it in an expression that I want to return?

Comment: Yes the one element list case for example declares `x` which is not used in an expression. It's largely useless to do so though.

Comment: There are two kinds of let, one is `let ... in ...` and one is just `let ... `. You don't want to use the second kind just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written is mostly nonesense:

```hs
swap1 let a = head x
```

for example is missing the `in <expr>` part of `let in` (there is a special variant without `in …` but that's only valid with `do` blocks and as extension on the bare ghci command line), also `x` isn't defined anywhere in that clause and all previous definitions are either a type, which doesn't make sense here, or a single item, which doesn't make sense in combination with `head` either.

From your code I'm guessing you meant to write the following function:

```hs
swap1 [] = error "empty list"
swap1 [_] = error "one element list"
swap1 (a:y) = let b = last y
                  z = init y
               in b:z ++ [a]
```